# Aspx Async call - Full domain server name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, windows-authentication

I have an ASPX page which calls a Web Service asynchronously:

```
   public async Task GetTypeAccess()
   {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await new Common.HttpClient().GetAsync("http://webserviceURL:port/Accounts/CurrentUser");
        string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            ..                
        }
        else
        {
           Response.Redirect("~/AccessDenied.html");
        }
    }
```

In the Page Load this method is registered as Asynchronous

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if(!IsPostBack)
     {
           RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(GetTypeAccess));
     }
}
```

The ASPX page is declared async

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind=...  Async="true" %>
```

Now, if the page is called using the IP address, or the Host Name, the web service call is fired, response is waited and user is authenticated:

```
http://IP_address:60815/Home/MainPage.aspx
http://hostname:60815/Home/MainPage.aspx
```

If, i call the page using the full domain name  (and updating the  with its full domain name) the web service call isn't fired, and opens the AccessDenied page.

```
http://hostname.subdomain.com:60815/Home/MainPage.aspx
```

Seems that the method, supposed to be asynchronous, is not actually "await"-ing for the call in this second case.

I actually cannot find the relation between the two things, but by simply changing both URLs (page and webserviceURL) including the full domain name, the behavior is different.

Using Windows authentication

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the method being async. If you were to change it to be synchronous I think you (the calling client) would receive the same error. Can you change the code to synchronous and try it? That would narrow down where you need to look to find the actual problem.

Comment: I agree with @Igor on this.  This has nothing at all to do with `async`!

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using for the site?

Comment: Sounded weird also for me. But i cannot find any explanation. I am using Windows authentication

Comment: I actually use the call to same exact call to that WS inside the ViewModel of a Silverlight Project, and it works in both cases ...